# Jquery submit function not validating

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have been working on a simple script for a class project. I am a new javascript student so this i giving me a hard time even though I think it can be solved easy. We the form is submitted, I input a 7 and get "wrong answer" which is good, but then I input 8 (correct answer) and it still outputs wrong answer. I do not know why it cannot differentiate any other number from 8. Please help

```
 $("#story").submit(function (e) {
var answer = document.getElementById('human-story');


if (answer != 8) {
    console.log(answer);
    e.preventDefault();         
}else {
    alert("right answer");
    e.preventDefault(); 
}
 })


<form class="form-horizontal contact" name="contact" method="post" action="" id="story">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4>We are excited to hear your story!</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="contact-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="First & Last Name" required="" >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="contact-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="you@example.com" required="">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="contact-message" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Story:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <textarea name="message"  rows="8" class="form-control" style="resize:none;" required=""></textarea>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label">5 + 3 = ?</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human-story" name="human-story" placeholder="Your Answer" required="">
      </div>
    </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        <button class="btn btn-success" name="submit-story" type="submit-story" value="Send!">Send</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: check value of answer at each submit! alert it and see what it gives!

Comment: Why not use: `if($(".form-control").val() == '8') { ... }else{ ... }` ?

Comment: why parse it to an integer?  Why not simply evaluate it as a string?

Comment: May be your _answer_ variable has _undefined_ value, so this will give always _true_ for this condition `if (answer != 8) {`

Comment: because If it is a string then any letter will allow it to go through if I do not use regex filtering. I am trying to pull the integer and see if it equals to the number 8. Philip100 - I tried your code but I keep getting "right answer" alert because all it confirming is that the input received  a number

Comment: Please Show your HTML. What is `console.log(answer);`?

Comment: @gio , Are you sure you have **only one** textfield with `form-control` class?

Comment: @epascarello  yea here i updated it now can you relook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one field with `.form-controll` class. Use `id` attribute to define which field have to be checked for the right answer:

```
$("#story").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    if ($("#human-story").val() == '8') {
        alert("right answer"); 
    } else {
        alert("wrong answer");
    }
});
```

Having multiple elements with `form-controll` class, using `$(".form-controll").val()` , jQuery returns value of the very first element with given class (in your case it's *"name"* field value).

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
$("#story").submit(function (e) {

    if ($(".form-control").val() == '8') {
       alert("right answer");    

    }else {
         alert("wrong answer"); 

    }
    e.preventDefault();     
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

first you can put e.preventDefault(); directly before you're setting the variable.
so you just have to write it once.

and y you don't just turn the if clause to

```
$("#story").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    var answer = parseInt($(".form-control").val(), 10);

    if (answer == 8) {
        alert("right answer"); 
    } else {
        alert("wrong answer");
    }
});
```

see working fiddle:

```js
$("#story").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var answer = parseInt($(".form-control").val(), 10);

  if (answer == 8) {
    alert("right answer");
  } else {
    alert("wrong answer");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="story">
  <input name="form--control" type="text" class="form-control" />
  <input name="submit" type="submit" class="form--submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: Would you explain us why `( answer != 8 )` doesn't work and `( answer == 8 )` works? You presented how, but no explanation about why.

Comment: this too, I tried it but whenever I input 8 it still alerts me wrong answer:(

Comment: I also get NaN for the console.log

Comment: the snippet works for me. i think its an integer/string problem. you can try if !== would work so it checks also variable type. else you can just don't parse the value to an integer, than it also should work.